# Is there a way to send CONTENT_LENGTH along with the content in reactor-netty

Tags: java, reactor-netty

My HttpServer responds to http get requests with some content. This content is relatively small but it may take a while to get it. As I understand reactive stack I should give a Mono or a Flux to an HttpServerResponse and my service should take background blocking IO in some threads other then Netty worker threads. For example:

```java
class SomeService {
    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = ...

    public Mono<String> load() {
        CompletableFuture<String> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        EXECUTOR.submit(() -> loadContent(future));
        Mono<String> ret = Mono.fromFuture(future).onErrorResume(Mono::error);
        return ret;
    }

    private void loadContent(CompletableFuture<String> cf) {
        String s = doBlockingLoadFromSomewhere();
        cf.complete(s);
    }
}

class Server {
    private SomeService loader;

    void activate() {
        InetSocketAddress address = getAddressSomehow();
        server = HttpServer.create()
                .host(address.getHostString())
                .port(address.getPort())
                .route(routes -> routes.get("/path", this::handlePath))
                .bindNow();
    }

    private Publisher<Void> handlePath(HttpServerRequest request, HttpServerResponse response)
    {
        Mono<String> contentMono = loader.load();
        return response.status(OK).sendString(contentMono);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine with one exception. I have to send a CONTENT_LENGTH header but reactor-netty does not set it automatically, so I have to do it myself.
I have an obvious way to block and count content length when it is available but it will block a Netty thread.
I have tried to compose the whole NettyOutbound in a Mono, but this loses a content completely, may be I did something wrong.

```java
    private Publisher<Void> handlePath(HttpServerRequest request, HttpServerResponse response)
    {
        Mono<String> contentMono = loader.load();
        Mono<NettyOutbound> handling = contentMono.flatMap(str -> {
            NettyOutbound r = response.status(OK)
                    .header(CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.valueOf(str.length()).toString())
                    .sendString(Mono.just(str), UTF_8);
            return Mono.just(r);
            });
        return handling.then();
    }
```

Please, tell me is there a canonical way of sending CONTENT_LENGTH (and in general composing a response headers upon content Mono is ready) without blocking the Netty worker thread?
In other words. All documentation samples compose response headers at once and compose a content at the moment when it is ready. How can I compose response headers and response content at the moment when the content is ready?

PS
I'm using io.projectreactor:reactor-core:3.2.5.RELEASE and io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.8.4.RELEASE

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but there's quite a few recent bugs relating to Netty and `content-length` vs `transfer-encoding: chunked`, see https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/553 and https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/614. I would upgrade if possible and retest, although it might be defaulting to chunked encoding if your `doBlockingLoadFromSomewhere()` is slow or streaming data back..

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I've upgraded to io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:0.8.9.RELEASE.
For the `return response.status(OK).chunkedTransfer(false).sendString(contentMono);`
I receive: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK connection: close`
And for the: `return response.status(OK).chunkedTransfer(true).sendString(contentMono);`
I get:`HTTP/1.1 200 OK transfer-encoding: chunked`
So reactor-netty is not going to calculate CONTENT_LENGTH itself.

Comment: There must be a reason why it's using chunked encoding and not setting the content-length, I would love to know what the rules are on this...